# Print dynamically allocated array of integers on single line

Tags: c, malloc

I'm trying to do the following:

Open a file with `up` to `1000` ints in a text file, 1 int per line.

Read the file line by line

Store the ints in a dynamically allocated array of 1000

Print the contents of the array on a single line

Yes this is homework, I'm stuck on this.

`Output should be: 
$ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ....`

What I have so far prints the integers on a new line after each iteration.

```
    int x = 0;
    char buf[1000];
    int  *array = (int *) malloc(1000 * sizeof(int));
    FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    while(fgets(buf, 1000, fp) != NULL) {
            array[x] = buf;
            printf("%s ", array[x]);
            x++;
    }       
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: `array[x] = strtod(buf, &endptr);`, etc.  Code is reading text.  Need to convert that to `int`.  Then print using `printf("%d ", array[x]);`  GTG

Comment: where do I add &endptr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code puts the buffer address in the integer array and then uses that as a string pointer for `printf()`, but you'll find it won't work if you try printing the array in a loop separate from the reading loop, because every element of the array holds this same buffer address. You should have been given a compiler warning about this.

This answer uses two loops, as you want to print the numbers after reading them.

```
while(fgets(buf, 1000, fp) != NULL && x < 1000)
    array[x++] = atoi(buf);

for (y=0; y<x; y++)
    printf("%d ", array[y]);

printf("\n");
```

Comment: Just a nitpick. `strtol` is a better function for converting to integers, although more complicated to use. `atoi` has no way to signal errors.

Comment: I moved the `newline` out of the loop, as OP's question stated "on a single line". The reason why he was getting a `newline` after every number (string) when there is not one in the code, is because `fgets()` keeps the `newline` that ends every line of the file (subject to a couple of provisos), at the end of the string it reads in.